# Getting information from roads API

Tags: api, road

I'm looking for api that i can use to get informations about roads (lightning condition , road type or surface condition) it should take as an  inputs latitude and longitude .
I found Bing road data api that gives informations about road type but it takes two cities names and google roads speed limits is not free.